# jQuery Autocomplete Plugin using Backbone JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js

Let's suppose I want to use jQueryUi for implemeting autocomplete in a backboneView having a form.

I implement the following code (*), 
but I don't like it because the fetching of the collection is performed also when the user does not type any letter.

How should I perform the fetching collection only when the user starts to type something in the input box?

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.myCollection = new MyCollection();
        this.myCollection.fetch(); // I would like to fetch the collection 
                                   // only when the user start to type the first letter  
    },
    events: {
        'focus #names': 'getAutocomplete'
    },

    getAutocomplete: function () {
        $("#names").autocomplete({
            source: JSON.stringify(this.myCollection)
        });
    }
});
```

---

P.S.:
the fetching should be performed just one time when the user types the first letter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work and only call fetch once.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this.myCollection = new MyCollection();
    this.collectionFetched = false;
  },
  events: {
    'focus #names': 'getAutocomplete'
    'keydown #names': 'fetchCollection'
  },
  fetchCollection: function() {
    if (this.collectionFetched) return;
    this.myCollection.fetch();
    this.collectionFetched = true;
  },
  getAutocomplete: function () {
    $("#names").autocomplete({
        source: JSON.stringify(this.myCollection)
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: maybe did you miss to add `this.collectionFetched = true` somewhere?

Comment: Actually I did post another similar question because I would like to fetch the collection in autocomplete module. For more details [Javascript module using jQueryUI.autocomplete and Backbone JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420391/javascript-module-using-jqueryui-autocomplete-and-backbone-js)

Comment: This is going to hid getAutocomplete every time you focus on names.  You might want to run that in initialize instead.

Answer (score 2):

try like this :

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.myCollection = new MyCollection();

    },
    events: {
        'focus #names': 'getAutocomplete',
        'keydown #names':'invokefetch'
    },
    invokefetch : function(){
       this.myCollection.fetch(); 
       $("#names").unbind( "keydown", invokefetch);
    },    
    getAutocomplete: function () {
        $("#names").autocomplete({
            source: JSON.stringify(this.myCollection)
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 thanks for your time. Actually I did post another similar question because I would like to fetch the collection in autocomplete module. For more details [Javascript module using jQueryUI.autocomplete and Backbone JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420391/javascript-module-using-jqueryui-autocomplete-and-backbone-js)